# Extraer graficas de una pagina web y mostrarla en un web view

Tags: java, android, webview

Estoy tratando de extraer unas gráficas de una página web para mostrarlas en un webview de mi aplicación Android.

Me estoy basando en el ejemplo de este post [*How to display a part of the webpage on the webview android*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477584/how-to-display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android) pero sigo sin lograrlo, ¿alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal o cómo podría solucionarlo?

Este en mi código de la app:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        //Activamos en JavaScript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Activamos el zoom
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        new BackgroundWorker().execute();
    }
    // load links in WebView instead of default browser

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @RequiresApi(21)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            getGraphics();
            return null;
        }
        public void getGraphics() {
            try {
                Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://amunet.com.mx/wordpress/index.php/graficas-de-3-tomas/").get();
                //Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://datos.botonmedico.com/pruebaJSOUP.html").get();
                //Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://darebee.com/").get();
                // Element element = htmlDocument.select("div#div1 > h3").first();
                Element element = htmlDocument.select("div#chart8").first();
                //Element element = htmlDocument.select("div#gkHeaderMod > div.darewod").first();
                System.out.println("Elemento: "+element);

                // replace body with selected element
                htmlDocument.body().empty().append(element.toString());
                final String html = htmlDocument.toString();
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
                    else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Que sucede o cual es el problema?

Comment: Mi problema es que no me logra extraer la gráfica asi como tengo la app.
La grafica esta dentro de un div, asi que realmente deberia ser bastante sencillo pero no logro extraerla, en mi app solo se ve en blanco.
He probado este codigo con otra pagina como puedes ver en el codigo comentado y si funciona, pero no se por que con estas graficas no.

Comment: Al cargar la url pide usuario y password...

Comment: Cierto una disculpa, el usuario es javier y la contraseña es 000000

Comment: lo primero que tiene que hacer tu aplicación es autenticarte

Comment: Si no lo haces te redireccionará al login

Answer (score 1):

Para desplegar el tipo de gráfica que necesitas no es suficiente tomar el `<div>` es necesario también tener los .js como son `canvasjs.min.js` y `jquery-2.2.3.min.js`, de hecho tendrías que habilitar la ejecución de `Javascript` para que la gráfica pudiera generarse sin problema.

Yo recomiendo cargues el url en el `WebView` pero para esto es necesario un `WebViewClient` y habilitar `Javascript` para lograr se genere la gráfica.

```
        String url = "http://amunet.com.mx/wordpress/index.php/graficas-de-3-tomas/";
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder @Elenasys, sabes se me dificulta entender por completo por que soy nuevo con los webviews, no se como obtener los js, podrías proporcionarme el código de las clases que mencionas?

Comment: Xavi si usas lo que comento en mi respuesta con eso es suficiente, prueba

Comment: Si lo hago como dices en efecto puedo puedo visualizar todas las graficas:
[ https://s29.postimg.org/6h55wcjw7/Screenshot_2016_12_20_17_36_26.png ] 

 Sin embargo no consigo extraer solo una grafica individual como deseo. Este es el link de las graficas que deseo extraer individualmente:
[ http://amunet.com.mx/wordpress/index.php/graficas-de-salud-2/ ]

Este es el proyecto de como lo hice:

[ https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OLQp2V8ILsd3JaclBqa3RfTU0 ]